# Join home and away results together in sports table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have code for both home and away results in separate queries but I'm unsure how to join this together to get both home and away.

CODE HOME Sports League

```
SELECT
teamName AS Team, 
 Sum(P) AS P,
Sum(W) AS W,
Sum(D) AS D,
 Sum(L) AS L,
SUM(F) as F,
SUM(A) AS A,
SUM(GD) AS GD,
SUM(Pts) AS Pts
  FROM(
  SELECT
  teamHomeID Team,
  1 P,
  IF(matchScoreHome > matchScoreAway,1,0) W,
  IF(matchScoreHome = matchScoreAway,1,0) D,
  IF(matchScoreHome < matchScoreAway,1,0) L,
  matchScoreHome F,
  matchScoreAway A,
  matchScoreHome-matchScoreAway GD,
  CASE WHEN matchScoreHome > matchScoreAway THEN 3 WHEN matchScoreHome =    matchScoreAway THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PTS
 FROM tblmatches WHERE matchstatus = 'FT' AND competitionID = 1 AND seasonID = 2     
) as tot
 JOIN tblteam t ON tot.team=t.teamID
 GROUP BY Team
 ORDER BY SUM(Pts) DESC ;
```

CODE AWAY Sports League

```
 SELECT
 teamName AS Team, 
 Sum(P) AS P,
 Sum(W) AS W,
 Sum(D) AS D,
 Sum(L) AS L,
 SUM(F) as F,
 SUM(A) AS A,
 SUM(GD) AS GD,
 SUM(Pts) AS Pts
 FROM(
 SELECT
 teamAwayID Team,
  1 P,
  IF(matchScoreHome < matchScoreAway,1,0) W,
  IF(matchScoreHome= matchScoreAway,1,0) D,
  IF(matchScoreHome > matchScoreAway,1,0) L,
  matchScoreAway F,
  matchScoreHome A,
  matchScoreAway-matchScoreHome GD,
 CASE WHEN matchScoreHome < matchScoreAway THEN 3 WHEN matchScoreHome = matchScoreAway THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PTS
 FROM tblmatches WHERE matchstatus = 'FT' AND competitionID = 1 AND seasonID = 2
) as tot
 JOIN tblteam t ON tot.team=t.teamID
 GROUP BY Team
 ORDER BY SUM(Pts) DESC ;
```

Each table will look like the follow

```
 --------------------------------------------------
 ¦ Team Name ¦ P ¦ W ¦ D ¦ L ¦ F  ¦ A  ¦ GD ¦ Pts ¦
 ¦ Man City  ¦ 8 ¦ 6 ¦ 0 ¦ 2 ¦ 23 ¦ 10 ¦ 13 ¦ 18  ¦
 ¦ Tottehham ¦ 8 ¦ 4 ¦ 4 ¦ 0 ¦ 14 ¦ 5  ¦ 9  ¦ 16  ¦
 --------------------------------------------------
```

I want to join both tables together to get something like the following:

```
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Team Name ¦ P ¦ W ¦ D ¦ L ¦ F ¦ A ¦ GD ¦ HW ¦ HD ¦ HL ¦ HF ¦ HA ¦ AW ¦ AD ¦ AL ¦ PTS ¦
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix would be to rename 'tot' to 'tothome' and 'totaway', then you can more or less merge the queries.

However, you then will have to reference e.g. F as totaway.F to get the goals the team scored in away matches.

And you will get ambiguity for P in SUM(P). There you have to SUM(tothome.P) + SUM(totaway.P) to get P.

Comment: thanks, I'm not sure how to merge th querys, I'm pretty new to SQL so trying but not getting very far